# Ruby - Class method that returns an instance & modifies that instance

Tags: ruby

Looking to set up a class method that can return an array of instances. I'm running into some trouble about the point where I try to modify the instances' variables `NoMethodError: undefined method 'name=' for #<Class:0x007fe65c8560c0>`.

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name

  def self.sample_users
    megan = self.class.new
    megan.name = "Megan"

    jack = self.class.new
    jack.name = "Jack"

    [megan, jack]
  end
end
```

I feel like this should be possible in Ruby. Any guidance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use just `new` instead of `self.class.new`

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name

  def self.sample_users
    megan = new
    megan.name = "Megan"

    jack = new
    jack.name = "Jack"

    [megan, jack]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of `self` in this context is `User` (`sample_users` is a class method); so `self.class` is going to return `Class`.

I think you just want `self.new`.